# export alias in makefile

Tags: linux, maven, makefile

I have Maven 3.6.3 installed in my machine and I use `mvn` to run it.

I defined an alias in .bashrc as follows : `alias mvn3=mvn`
So now I can do :

```
mvn3 dependency:copydependencies
```

Now, I have a makefile with the following command :

```
dependencies:
  mvn3 dependency:copydependencies
```

But when I run

```
make dependencies
```

I have the following error :

```
mvn3 dependency:copy-dependencies
/bin/sh: 1: mvn3: not found
```

I dont want to change the Makefile.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: As make tells you it uses `/bin/sh` to execute the recipes. So your `.bashrc` is ignored for a first reason: the shell is not bash (or bash but run as sh). But it is also ignored for a second reason: a non-interactive sh shell does not read any startup file. If you want to use bash to execute the recipes, and to source `~/.bashrc`, without modifying your Makefile you can try `make SHELL=bash BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc`.

Comment: But as `~/.bashrc` files are usually not written to be sourced by non-interactive shells. A better solution could be to create a file with just this alias definition (or even better a function definition), let's say `~/.mvn3`, and run make with `make SHELL=bash BASH_ENV=~/.mvn3`.

Comment: Why do you use such an old version of Maven? Use more recent version... furthermore why do you try to use a Makefile? Why do you need to copydependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are a feature for interactive shells. There are ways to force the issue, but the best solution by far is to decouple your Makefile from your personal interactive Bash configuration.

If you want the command for `mvn` to be overrideable, a common convention is to use a `make` variable for the command.

```
# you can override this with make MVN=/path/to/your/mvn or etc
MVN := mvn

dependencies:
    $(MVN) dependency:copydependencies
```

... but in your case, simply hardcoding `mvn` may well be completely acceptable, and actually a better solution.

If you absolutely don't want to change the Makefile, you can replace your alias with a shell function (which still needs to be loaded into noninteractive shells somehow if you need it there) or a simple wrapper on your PATH:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec mvn "$@"
```

You would save this script as `mvn3` in a directory somewhere in your `PATH` and `chmod +x` it. (A common arrangement is to create `$HOME/bin` for your personal utilities and wrappers, and make sure your shell is configured to add this directory to your `PATH` in both interactive and noninteractive shells.)